# iOS - Set UIToolBarItem on UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbaritem

I drag out a toolbaritem in storyboard and set it on my nav controller, but when I run my code it's not there, is there something I'm missing?

EDIT:

Tried setting it in code as well in my viewDidLoad method:

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Map" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(viewMap)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;
```

Won't work either.

Here's how it's set up in my storyboard:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Just found my problem. In my controller code when I update it's contents I change the right bar button item for a spinner and never set it back to what it had before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UINavigationController` already has a toolbar built in.  It has a property `toolBarHidden` which is set to `YES` by default, which is why it is not normally seen.  If you are using storyboard you can easily make the built-in bottom toolbar visible by checking the checkbox "Shows Toolbar" in the inspector when the Navigation Controller is selected.

See the [UINavigationController documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.

EDIT:

Ok, it sounds like what you are trying to do is add a right button to your view controller's `UINavigationItem`.  To do this in storyboard, drag a "Bar Button Item" from the Objects Library onto the Navigation Item in your ViewController.  You can then set the title/style/etc of the bar button item.  If nothing still shows up when you run your app, make sure that your ViewController is connected properly with a segue to the navigation controller.

Also make sure you are adding the Bar Button Item to your view controller's Navigation Item, NOT to the View Controller itself.  Here is how the setup should look in your storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Ok, maybe it's not the toolbar I want to set, but the right bar button the navigation controller has

Comment: And I didn't drag out a tool bar btw, just a toolbar item to set it on the navigation bar

Comment: I drag it into my view controller and set it on the navbar, it won't show up also tried setting it in my viewDidLoad metod, didn't work either

Comment: Thanks for the screen, I've set it up like that, and it won't show

Comment: @jonkroll: Can't we add more than one bar button items to the navigationItem using the storyBoard ??

Comment: Just to be very explicit: if a toolbar is added to the scene, it is *not* referenced by self.navigationController.toolbar - this is the default one owned by the navigationController and can be turned on/off by all controllers in the navigationController. Totally confusing!

Answer (score 1):

To add an item to a navigation bar, you need to add a `Bar Button Item` to the Navigation *Item* contained in the view controller. Go to your storyboard, find the right VC, and find the navigation item (it's in the hierarchy shown in the navigation controller 'scene'). Just drag a Bar Button Item into that hierarchy underneath the nav item, or directly onto the navbar in the visual builder display.

The navigation controller only looks at your VC's nav item when that VC is pushed onto the stack; hence modifying the VC's nav item in `viewDidLoad` has no effect.

(I've done this *programmatically* before but I don't have the code with me, so maybe I'll add that later...)

Comment: If you look at the image in my question, you'll see that that's what I did, and it won't work

Comment: How did you get the nav bar to show up in the VC in question? Did you embed the view in a navigation controller (such that your storyboard shows tab bar controller -> nav controller -> VC)?

Comment: Yep, just hit embed in nav controller

Comment: Based on the answers from jonkroll and me, it seems like you're doing the right thing, but something (like the way you're transitioning into the nav controller) is causing the problem. I suggest starting with a new empty project and getting it to work, and then gradually make the new project more complex until it breaks or you figure out what's different.